# Can I have more than 1 aura active at the same time?

Tags: dnd-4e, aura

Can I have more than 1 aura active at the same time?

Example, can one character have both:

- **[Aura of Peace](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/paragonpath.aspx?id=404)** (peace of messenger paragon path lvl 16)
- **[Skald's Aura](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=15849)** (bard utility)

active?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes to both the general and specific cases.**

## Multiple Auras In general:

While unconsciousness will end an Aura, an aura that is not a product of a Stance will be unaffected by other Auras up save through explicit mention of the rules.

There is nothing, for example, to prevent a  skald multiclassing as a cavalier to have both her skald's aura up and the defender's aura at the same time. Also given that at least one of those auras is at-will, it can be presumed to be "always up" and does not need specific activation at the start of combat.

[Aura](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=344)

> An aura is a continuous effect that emanates from a
>   creature. Unless otherwise noted, an aura uses the following rules.
>
> Fills an Area: The aura fills the creature’s space and each square
>   that is both within a specified distance of the creature and within
>   line of effect of it. For instance, an aura 1 affects each square
>   adjacent to the creature. A creature is normally unaffected by its own
>   aura.
>
> Unaffected by the Environment: The aura is unaffected by environmental
>   phenomena and terrain, although blocking terrain blocks an aura. For
>   instance, an aura of fire is unaffected by an area of extreme cold.
>
> Overlapping Auras: If auras overlap and impose penalties to the same
>   roll or game statistic, a creature affected by the overlapping auras
>   is subjected to the worst penalty; the penalties are not cumulative.
>   For instance, if a creature is affected by three overlapping auras
>   that each impose a -2 penalty to attack rolls, the creature takes a -2
>   penalty, not a -6 penalty.
>
> Deactivating an Aura: A creature can take a minor action to deactivate
>   or reactivate one of its auras. However, certain auras have set
>   durations and cannot be reactivated after they end.
>
> Death or Unconsciousness Ends: A creature’s auras end immediately when
>   it falls unconscious or dies.

## Bard and PP Feature

The Skald's aura is an aura produced by the class utility power and governed by the aura rules above.

The "Aura of Peace" is a class feature. It is not an aura and obeys none of the rules for auras because it does not have the aura keyword and because it is not a power. It just works.